# Why XOR function does not print out the expected hex value?

Tags: python, encryption, xor, bitwise-xor

So I have the following function and I wonder why when I xor X and Y, it does not print out the hex value as expected_result? Is there anything I need to add? Am I missing something in the function?

```
def xor(X, Y):
  return "".join([chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(X, Y)])
X = "Hello World"
Y = "supersecret"
print(xor(X,Y))
```

expected_result = "3b101c091d53320c000910"

Comment: You *always* want to include a language / runtime tag. This also triggers syntax highlighting for the correct language.

Comment: I see you have 2 earlier questions about the same subject. Do you maybe need a deeper explanation? Happy to provide it, just ask in the comments. Because it doesn't seem you are learning anything at the moment...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for the notice. I am actually learning. I already knew how to encrypt a text with a key using XOR and also encoding it using hex value. The function I am asking here is from a class. I would say I understand 80% of what it does but I feel like I am missing something that it does not print in human-readable character. You are very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting the part where you need to convert the resulting **bytes** to hexadecimals. Instead, you convert the bytes directly to characters, which means that you are decoding bytes that themselves may not be printable.

Here is the code where the binary result of the two encoded character values (using `ord`) are converted to hex before being printed.

```
def xor(X, Y):
  return "".join('{:02x}'.format(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(X, Y))
X = "Hello World"
Y = "supersecret"
print(xor(X,Y))
```

Note that this fixes the issue. However, the `xor` function should really be returning a binary array. Ciphertext is generally binary, hexadecimals are just used to make them presentable for human consumption:

```
def xor(X, Y):
  return bytes([(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(X, Y)])
X = "Hello World"
Y = "supersecret"
print(xor(X,Y).hex())
```

Note that I've used Python 3, which is strongly recommended if you want to perform many conversions and handle byte arrays.